# why i get this error when i try to scroll through a list to its last element?

Tags: c, sorting, linked-list, dynamic-memory-allocation, singly-linked-list

Im trying to resolve the [21. Merge Two Sorted Lists](https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-two-sorted-lists/) on leetCode. The problem is composed as follows: I have two linked lists already ordered in ascending order and I have to combine them into a single list that is also ordered in ascending order.

This is my code:

```
struct ListNode *sortList(struct ListNode *headList) {
    struct ListNode *ptrHead = headList;
    int temp;
    if(headList == NULL)
    return NULL;

    while(ptrHead->next != NULL){
        if(ptrHead->val > ptrHead->next->val){
            temp = ptrHead->val;
            ptrHead->val = ptrHead->next->val;
            ptrHead->next->val = temp;
            ptrHead = headList;
        }else{
            ptrHead = ptrHead->next;
        }
    }

    return headList;
}

void addNode(struct ListNode **list, int data){
      struct ListNode *newNode = (struct ListNode *) malloc(sizeof (struct ListNode)), *temp = NULL;

      if((*list) == NULL){
          newNode->val = data;
          newNode->next = NULL;
          (*list) = newNode;
      }else{
          temp = (*list);
          while (temp->next != NULL){
              temp = temp->next;
          }
          newNode->val = data;
          temp->next = newNode;
      }
}

struct ListNode *mergeTwoLists(struct ListNode *l1, struct ListNode *l2){
    struct ListNode *newList = NULL;

    while (l1 != NULL){
        addNode(&newList, l1->val);
        l1 = l1->next;
    }
    while (l2 != NULL){
        addNode(&newList, l2->val);
        l2 = l2->next;
    }

    return sortList(newList);
}
```

I tried to run it locally and I had no problem but when I go to run it on the leet code I get an error

The error:

```
    Line 19: Char 20: runtime error: member access within misaligned address 
    0xbebebebebebebebe for type 'struct ListNode', which requires 8 byte alignment 
    [solution.c]
    0xbebebebebebebebe: note: pointer points here
    <memory cannot be printed>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `addNode` has a bug. You forgot to set the data member `next` to `NULL` in this code snippet

```
  }else{
      temp = (*list);
      while (temp->next != NULL){
          temp = temp->next;
      }
      newNode->val = data;
      temp->next = newNode;
  }
```

You need to write at least

```
  }else{
      temp = (*list);
      while (temp->next != NULL){
          temp = temp->next;
      }
      newNode->val = data;
      newNode->Next = NULL;
      temp->next = newNode;
  }
```

The reason of the error is a duplicated code. I would define the function the following way

```
int addNode( List **list, int data )
{
    struct ListNode *newNode = malloc( sizeof ( *newNode ) );
    int success = newNode != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        newNode->val  = data;
        newNode->next = NULL;

        while ( *list ) list = &( *list )->next;
        *list = newNode;
    }

    return success;
}
```

Pay attention to that using two different names for the same entity like `List` and `struct ListNode` confuses readers of the code.

And to merge two lists there is no need to create copies of the lists as you are doing in the function `mergeTwoLists`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and it was really helpful I corrected the code with your suggestions on both StackOverflow and LeetCode, regarding the structure entities thank you very much again.